# Converting a column stored as a price string to double numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, type-conversion

I have a column in a table named price that has values that are strings like so:

```
$170.00
```

How can I use SQL to convert these price strings into double numbers?

I am using Postgresql with Heroku

Comment: always specify which database you are using

Comment: 1. Strip of $.  2. Write a regex to ensure the values are in the correct format.  3. If it's valid, cast it.

Comment: Example: `select regexp_replace('$120.12', '(\W)', '', '')::decimal`